# The incoming scene allocates before the current scene can pass data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to pass data (score) between two scenes.However, my second scene is allocating before the first scene can pass the data. Not sure why. My code:

MainScreen.m

```
-(void)gameOver
{

     self.view.scene.userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     [self.view.scene.userData setObject:self.score forKey:@"score"];

     SVGGameOverScreen *gameOverScreen = [[SVGGameOverScreen alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
     gameOverScreen.view.scene.userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     [gameOverScreen.userData setObject:[self.view.scene.userData objectForKey:@"score"] forKey:@"score"];

     NSLog(@"Value of score (FIRST SCREEN): %d", self.score.intValue);
     NSLog(@"Value of object for score key (FIRST SCREEN) %@", [self.userData objectForKey:@"score"]);

     [self.backgroundMusicPlayer stop];

     //Transition to new view
     SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionUp duration:1.0];
     transition.pausesOutgoingScene = YES;
     [self.view presentScene:gameOverScreen transition:transition];
}
```

GameOverScreen.m

```
in init method
...
 self.score = [[NSNumber alloc]init];
        self.score = [self.userData objectForKey:@"score"];
        NSLog(@"Value of object for score key (SECOND SCREEN) %@", [self.userData objectForKey:@"score"]);
```

Output is as follows when gameOver is called:

```
2013-12-18 15:47:48.646 [] Value of object for score key (SECOND SCREEN) (null)
2013-12-18 15:47:48.700 [] Value of score (FIRST SCREEN): 26
2013-12-18 15:47:48.700 [] Value of object for score key (FIRST SCREEN) 26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call

```
[SVGGameOverScreen alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
```

and don't set the userData inside it, of course it won't be set until after the method returns. Either write a new method which reproduces whatever logic you need to do after userData is set, pass it into the game over screen with a new method like this

```
initWithSize: (CGSize) size userData: (NSMutableDictionary*) userData
```

and set it inside, or (probably better) make a custom setter for the property and put the logic there.

Incidentally, why are you creating an NSNumber for score only to set it equal to the value userData's "score" key?

Comment: What would you suggest instead for your concern about the NSNumber?

Comment: Getting rid of that line altogether. There's no point initializing a new NSNumber only to set score equal to something else on the very next line.